# Concatenacion de Strings en C con Memoria Dinamica

Tags: c, punteros, manejo-de-memoria, string

¿Podrían darme una mano con el siguiente ejercicio?
Realizar las siguientes funciones (revisar qué funciones de Ansi C nos pueden ayudar): `char* string_concat(const char*, const char*)`.

Estoy intentando usar `malloc` y punteros para practicar el tema, pero no estoy pudiendo identificar cual es el problema que estoy teniendo a la hora de devolver el puntero e imprimirlo en consola

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* string_concat(char* p1, char* p2){
    char* concatenacion = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(p1)+strlen(p2)+1));
    concatenacion = strcat(p1,p2);
    return concatenacion;
}

int main(void){
    char* nombre = "Ritchie";
    char* saludo = "Hola ";
    printf("El nombre es: %s \n",nombre);
    printf("%s",string_concat(saludo,nombre));
    return 0;
}
```

Luego de compilar y correr tengo la siguiente salida

```
El nombre es: Ritchie
```

Además, entiendo que al estar trabajando con memoria dinámica debo liberar el heap para que este no producir leak memory. Para ello debo usar free pero no se donde y ¿sólo basta con `free(&concatenacion)` en el caso que se adentro de la función?

Por otro lado no entiendo cual es la diferencia de trabajar con `const char*` y `char *`. En mi caso lo deje como char* ya que me presentaba un error de tipos a la hora de compilar.

Como un plus quería evitar declarar mi array como `"Hola "`, lo correcto debería ser trabajar con `"Hola"` sin el espacio que agregue. Se que debería usar `strncat` pero desconozco el funcionamiento de la función.

Answer (score 5):

Si echamos un ojo a la documentación de `strcat( )`:

> `char *strcat( char *dest, const char *src );`
>
> #### DESCRIPCIÓN
>
> La  función `strcat( )` une la cadena *src* a la cadena *dest* sobreescribiendo el caracter `\0` al final de *dest*, y entonces añade un caracter final `\0`. Las  cadenas  no deben solaparse, y la cadena *dest* debe tener suficiente espacio para el resultado.
>
> #### VALOR DEVUELTO
>
> `strcat( )` devuelve un puntero que apunta a la cadena resultante *dest*.

Con lo anterior en mente, tu problema es, simplemente, que estás usando mal la función `strcat( )`:

```
char* string_concat( const char *p1, const char *p2 ) {
  char *concatenacion = malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( p1 ) + strlen( p2 ) ) + 1 );

  // strcat( ) NECESITA un 0 al final de la cadena destino.
  *concatenacion = 0;

  // Ahora la llamamos 2 veces, 1 para cada cadena a añadir.
  strcat( concatenacion, p1 );
  strcat( concatenacion, p2 );

  return concatenacion;
}
```

> Para ello debo usar `free( )` pero no se donde

Pues cuando ya no necesites mas la memoria. En tu caso, sería **después** de mostrarla. Pero, para ello, necesitas un puntero a la memoria que quieres liberar:

```
const char *concatenacion = string_concat( saludo, nombre );
printf( "%s", concatenacion );
free( concatenacion );
```

> Por otro lado no entiendo cual es la diferencia de trabajar con `const char *` y `char *`

Esto da para una respuesta completa ... de entrada la posición del `const` es importante: **no** es lo mismo `const char *` que `char *const`.

Limitándonos a tu código, es simple: un puntero `const` **no puede modificar aquello a lo que apunta**. Por lo tanto, en tu ejemplo, el puntero destino **no puede ser `const`** puesto que vas a modificar los bytes a los que apunta. Sin embargo, las cadenas *origen*, aquellas que vas tan solo a leer, **pueden** ser `const` perfectamente. Fíjate que digo `pueden`: nada te obliga a declararlas `const`, pero, haciéndolo, el compilador te avisará si intentas modificarlas y te evitarás errores.

> Como un plus queria evitar declarar mi array como "Hola ", lo correcto deberia ser trabajar con "Hola" sin el espacio que agregué.

Te basta con llamar a `strcat( )` **3 veces** (y añadir un *byte* para el espacio extra):

```
char* string_concat( const char *p1, const char *p2 ) {
  char *concatenacion = malloc( sizeof( char ) * ( strlen( p1 ) + strlen( p2 ) ) + 2 );

  // strcat( ) NECESITA un 0 al final de la cadena destino.
  *concatenacion = 0;

  // Ahora la llamamos 3 veces, 1 para cada cadena a añadir, y otra para el espacio:
  strcat( concatenacion, p1 );
  strcat( concatenacion, " " );
  strcat( concatenacion, p2 );

  return concatenacion;
}
```